# Toggle between two variables using jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, button, toggle

I have a sample [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sc2jjk2/) where I can toggle the value of a variable on click of a button as,

```
 if(columnNumber == 11)
  {
columnNumber = 0;  
  }
  else {
  columnNumber = 11; 
  }
```

Is there any other simple function in jquery to do the same?

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery for something that is already simple in pure Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions to toggle DOM element classes or visibility, but AFAIK **there is nothing to toggle simple javascript variable**. (jQuery isn't really meant to do that)

Also I highly recommend that you use "used-as-constant" variables for better maintainability, like in http://jsfiddle.net/9sc2jjk2/1/

```
var FIRST_VALUE = 11;
var SECOND_VALUE = 0;
columnNumber = (columnNumber == FIRST_VALUE) ? SECOND_VALUE : FIRST_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a jquery function to toggle variable's value, but you can use ternary operator in above situation like bellow using pure javascript.

```
columNumber = (columNumber==11)?0:11
```

Comment: for more info check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807736/any-way-to-toggle-between-two-strings-using-one-piece-of-javascript