# Toggle string variable on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a variable called `value`. `value` is a string that can either be "*true*" or "*false*".

`value` by default is set to "*false*".

On button click, I want to toggle the value or `value`. So on first button click, `value` will be "*true*" (because it's false by default), and then, when clicked again, change to "*false*", and so on.

I have tried ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807736/any-way-to-toggle-between-two-strings-using-one-piece-of-javascript)):

`value.val(value.val() == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false');`

But no success.

**Here's a demo:**

```js
$(function() {

  const button = $(".button");
  var value = "false";

  $(button).click(function() {
  
    console.log("click");

    // if (value == "false") {
    //  value = "true";
    // } else if (value == "false") {
    //  value = "false";
    // }

    value.val(value.val() == "false" ? "true" : "false");

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="button">
  click me
</button>
```

Comment: Can you not use a boolean for this? It's far better practice and makes flipping the state much easier: `value = !value;`

Comment: I think you are using jQuery's HTML input element value updating code to update the value of a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Your code should be `button.val(value == "false" ? "true" : "false");`

Comment: OP is not asking to change value of button...```button.val(value == "false" ? "true" : "false");``` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a boolean value for the `value` variable instead of using `string`. This way, you can use the "not" operator (`!`) to reverse the value of the boolean.

**EDIT**
It's also worth noting that you're using `.val()` method on a variable, which the method is not really used for. `.val()` method is used for inputs such as `<input>` and `<textarea>` tags. You can simply get the value of the variable by just putting the variable name in the code.

**Example:**

```js
var value = 1;
alert(value);
```

This code will alert and show the value of `value` variable, where as `value.val()` will return an error.

**Here's a demo:**

```js
var value = false;
$("#btn").click(function() {
  value = !value;
  $("#value").html(value ? value : "false");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="value">false</span><br><br>
<button id="btn">Toggle Value</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  let value = "false";

  $(".button").on("click", function() {
    value = value === "false" ? "true" : "false";
    console.log(value);
  });

});
```

```html
<button class="button">click me</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```