# Use a checkbox to toggle between 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

**How do I use a checkbox in `JS`/`jQuery` to toggle just between 2 numbers?**

I want unchecked to always be `$0` and checked to always be `$100`. The code below comes close. I'm looking to use `str.replace` as opposed to switching `divs` using `display:none`.

**Code:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  let str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.replace("$0", "$100");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript String</h2>

<p>The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression,
and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.</p>

<p id="demo">$0</p>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" value="Try It">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807736/any-way-to-toggle-between-two-strings-using-one-piece-of-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById('demo')

  element.innerText = element.innerText === '$0' ? '$100' : '$0'
}
```

Comment: Updated my typo, try again.  That should work.

Comment: You (both) should be using `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: you may be able to help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672362/checkbox-toggle-and-duplicate-div-value . Thanks