# checkbox toggle and duplicate div value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, getelementbyid

I'm using the following script to toggle between 2 set values $0 and $53,498 in the middle div #t1.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
                            <div class="col-md-4 themed-grid-col"><label><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"  onclick="t1()"> Tuition</label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 themed-grid-col"><div id="t1">$0</div></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 themed-grid-col"><div id="t1-total"></div></div> 
                          </div>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById('demo')

  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML === '$0' ? '$53,498' : '$0'
}
```

As I toggle between the 2 values $0 and $53,498 how do I apply the toggled value to the last div #t1-total.
As per screenshot[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhaT8.png) I want the value in div 3 to equal the value in div 2 as I toggle the checkbox in div 1.

I only seem to be able to retrieve the $0 value and never $53,498.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here as TEXT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById('demo')

  element.innerText = element.innerText === '$0' ? '$53,498' : '$0'

  document.getElementById('t1-total').innerText = element.innerText
}
```

EDIT: Since you're asking about it in comments -> full example.

```
let tuitionFee = 0
let activityFee = 0

const toggle () => {
  const tuition = document.getElementById('tuition')
  const activity = document.getElementById('activity')
  const total = document.getElementById('total')

  tuitionFee = tuitionFee === 0 ? 100 : 0
  activityFee = activityFee === 0 ? 100 : 0

  tuition.innerText = '$' + tuitionFee
  activity.innerText = '$' + activityFee
  total.innerText = '$' + (tuitionFee + activityFee)
}
```

Now call your toggle function.

Comment: Fantastic. You Rock! :)

Comment: In function 2 do -> ````document.getElementById('t1-total').innerText = document.getElementById('demo').innerText````

Comment: wondering how I sum these 2 value to a div with id total: ` function t1() {
     var e1 = document.getElementById('t1'); e1.innerText = e1.innerText === '$0' ? '$53,498' : '$0'; 
     document.getElementById('t1-total').innerText = e1.innerText;
    } //Tuition
  
    function t2() {
    var  e2 = document.getElementById('t2'); e2.innerHTML = e2.innerHTML === '$0' ? '120' : '$0';
     document.getElementById('t2-total').innerText = e2.innerText } //Activity Fee` ...those code backticks aint working for me

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: cant get that full example to work unfortunately. Doesn't seem to be pulling the right values

Comment: This makes it easier to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68674083/summing-divs-using-checkbox-toggle

Answer (score 0):

```js
function t1(){
    const element = document.getElementById('t1-total');

    element.innerHTML = ((element.innerHTML === '$0' || element.innerHTML.trim() == '') ? '$53,498' : '$0');
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col-md-4 themed-grid-col">
    <label><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"  onclick="t1()">  Tuition</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 themed-grid-col"><div id="t1">$0</div></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 themed-grid-col" id="t1-total"> </div> 
</div>
```